# What is `confirmButton` in NerdDinner's ActionResult Delete?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nerddinner

In the NerdDinner MVC app demo, there is `confirmButton` defined when setting up `ActionResult Delete`:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id, string confirmButton) {
```

What is `confirmButton` for, as it is not used in the code? I assumed it returned the name of the submit button that was clicked, but it is just a blank string. How can you get which button was pressed (e.g. you could have `archive` and a `delete` (or `yes` , `no`) buttons on the same page)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the View `Delete.aspx` you'll see the following html...

```
<h2>
    Delete Confirmation
</h2>

<div>
    <p>Please confirm you want to cancel the dinner titled: 
    <i> <%:Model.Title %>? </i> </p>
</div>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>

    <input name="confirmButton" type="submit" value="Delete" />        

<% } %>
```

As you can see the confirmButton is located here and the value will be passed to the ActionResult you specified.

You can also specify two buttons like...

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>

    <input name="confirmButton" type="submit" value="Delete" />        
    <input name="confirmButton" type="submit" value="Something Else" />        

<% } %>
```

The `confirmButton` parameter will have the value of whichever one you clicked...

Why it isn't working properly for you in NerdDinner is strange though but you can easily test this by creating a quick project and opening the default HomeController and adding

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string confirmButton) {
        return View();
    }
```

In the Index.aspx you can add

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>

    <input name="confirmButton" type="submit" value="Delete" />        
    <input name="confirmButton" type="submit" value="Something Else" />        

<% } %>
```

And you should be good to go.